# How to setup requests per second scenario on JMeter

Tags: jmeter, throughput, threadgroup

My test has 1 Authentication API and 2 other API's. I need to run Authentication API once and other 2 API's to generate X request per minute.The Auth API should run first then followed by other 2 API's. How can I create this scenario in thread group.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your "Authentication API" (whatever it is) under the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)
2. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) is a good option but be aware of several constraints, i.e.

   - it is precise enough on "**minute**" level, the throughput will be applied more or less after 1st minute of your test, prior to that you need to manipulate the ramp-up period
   - it can only **pause** the JMeter [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) execution rate to **limit** it to the defined number of requests per second, it won't kick off any extra threads in case if current amount is not enough to conduct the required load
   - If you want to get the number of requests per second you set in the "Target throughput" make sure that "Calculate Throughput based on" is set to `all active threads`

     [image]

In the majority of cases it's easier to use [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)